# Is this correct way dependency injection in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

So I am new to Angular, I have been reading around the subject of dependency injection.

I added this function into my app but keep getting a eslint error :

> You should use the function syntax for DI

I can not see anything wrong with what I have declared. Can anyone help?

```
angular.module('tools').config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) { 
        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo : '/404' });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
    }
]);
```

the exact message I get is 
" 1:1  error  You should use the function syntax for DI  angular/di"

Comment: this looks right to me. Not sure why you get this error. Maybe post the entire error message, if there is some detail you're missing.

Comment: it's also better to use this version vs the one with only the function, so that you don't get a mess while minifying.

Comment: looks correct to me.

Comment: Could it be  configuration with eslint???

Comment: there is an open issue somewhere: https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular/issues/223

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with the default configuration of eslint-plugin-angular. Just put in

```
/*eslint angular/di: [2,"array"]*/
```

at the beginning of your js file and see if the error disappears. If so, add

```
"angular/di": [2, "function"]
```

to your eslint config

**Note:** eslint requires you to use consistent dependency injection, so you'll always have to use the same style of dependency injection you choose for your project

Source: [eslint-plugin-angular docs](https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: It looks like that was the problem thanks, so will add the rule into my config file.

Comment: Whichever way should be fine as long as you're consistent and you remember to be careful with pure function DI with minification. Technically speaking, array DI takes a slight bit of extra manual work and attention so be careful with that if you go this route. *note:* according to John Papa's angular style guide, you should avoid both function and array dependency injection and go for the $inject style. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/README.md#style-y091

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling the linting, you could also actually move it to a function.

If you are using something like ngInject, you could do:

```
angular.module('tools').config(myRoutConfig);


/** @ngInject */
function myRoutConfig($routeProvider, $locationProvider) { 
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo : '/404' });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
}
```

Hope this helps someone!